# im trying to use google charts and it show me a blank page im using laravel 5.4

Tags: php, json, laravel, google-visualization

This is the view file I dont know what's going on please help!

```
<html>
          <head>
            <!--Load the Ajax API-->
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">


           <script type="text/javascript">

        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gantt']});

        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() {

              // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
               var jsonData = $.ajax({
                    url: "getData.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false
                    }).responseText;

                var options = {
                  height: 400,
                  gantt: {
                    trackHeight: 30
                  }
                };

         var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

              // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
              // Do not forget to check your div ID
        var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);

            }

            </script>
          </head>

          <body>
            <!--this is the div that will hold the GANT chart-->
           <div id="chart_div"></div>
          </body>
        </html>
```

*this the code of getData.php *

```
   <?php 

      $con=mysqli_connect("localhost" , 'root' ,  '' , 'planification' );

      // Check connection
      if (mysqli_connect_errno())


    {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

      $query = "SELECT * FROM `gants` WHERE 1";

      $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

      $rows = array();


       while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $rows[] = $r;
      }

          echo json_encode($rows);

          mysqli_close($con);

        ?>
```

file location
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trfbi.png)

this is the content of getData file

C:\Users\ahmed\Ph-r-p>php getData.php

```
[{"0":"DHDJJ","Task ID":"DHDJJ","1":"DCNJNDSNDS","Task Name":"DCNJNDSNDS","2":"NDNDNS","Resource":"NDNDNS","3":"2017-04-03","Start Date":"2017-04-03","4":"2017-04-05","End Date":"2017-04-05","5":null,"Duration":null,"6":"100","Percent Complete":"100","7":null,"Dependencies":null},{"0":"dhsg","Task ID":"dhsg","1":"djbs","Task Name":"djbs","2":"djsn","Resource":"djsn","3":"2017-04-05","Start Date":"2017-04-05","4":"2017-04-08","End Date":"2017-04-08","5":null,"Duration":null,"6":"12","Percent Complete":"12","7":null,"Dependencies":null},{"0":"DKJNDES","Task ID":"DKJNDES","1":"DDNS","Task Name":"DDNS","2":"DKNS","Resource":"DKNS","3":"2017-04-09","Start Date":"2017-04-09","4":"2017-04-12","End Date":"2017-04-12","5":null,"Duration":null,"6":"10","Percent Complete":"10","7":null,"Dependencies":null},{"0":"FKSNJ","Task ID":"FKSNJ","1":"LKQSDFJ","Task Name":"LKQSDFJ","2":"QSJDH","Resource":"QSJDH","3":"2017-04-10","Start Date":"2017-04-10","4":"2017-04-14","End Date":"2017-04-14","5":null,"Duration":null,"6":"100","Percent Complete":"100","7":null,"Dependencies":null}]
```

Comment: this issue in this particular page? check your error logs and see,

Comment: in order to create a `new google.visualization.DataTable` directly from `jsonData`, [it must be is a specific format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)

Answer (score 0):

In laravel, `public` folder is only accessible from `url`. So you should put `getData.php` in `public` folder. And use it like this in your `ajax` :

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
                url: "public/getData.php",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false
                }).responseText;
```

It seems like you are really new to any MVC structure. You should start learning MVC and structure of laravel. You should user laravel route and controller. Here is the video series to learn laravel from scrath : https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch

Comment: thank you for your answer but still show me blank page. i've already tried to create json file in my controller but it didn't work so i tried this one !

Comment: this the code  `   public function GetGant()
      {   
         $query = Gant::all() ;
         $results = array();   
          $results = $query ;
      $gant =  json_encode($results);

return view('ordonnancement')->withGant($gant) ;


      }
`

Comment: sorry this the first time i use stackflow :(